# discord.py rewrite delete author message

Tags: python, discord.py

How would I delete the message that triggered the function in discord.py? I would like it to delete !test and then continue the function.

EDIT: The solution is `await ctx.message.delete()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the message from the context and then delete it.

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```